# Is there a way i can see why Squid (Proxy Server) determines why a resources should be a MISS?

Tags: proxy, squid, cache

I'm using Fiddler/FireBug to debug some of our live server web content. We're getting a lot of :-

X-Cache: MISS from 
X-Cache-Lookup: MISS from :8080
Via: 1.1 :8080 (squid/2.7.STABE3)

I thought i knew a lot about cache-control / expires / last-modified / etags, etc.. but maybe not.

So .. is there a way I can run squid in some verbose way to see why it thinks a resource which i request, is cached/is not getting cached, etc.. which is why we're getting MISSes back?

cheers :)

Comment: Maybe the reason is response in HTTP 1.1. squid is not supporting http 1.1 currently. here is some answers. http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/HTTP11

Comment: Shouldn't the server recognise that an HTTP 1.0 request was made and respond in kind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manipulate the log output with the debug_options directive.

EDITED:
Something like

```
debug_options ALL,1 11,3 31,3 65,3
```

Refer to the cvs [here](http://www.squid-cache.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb.cgi/squid/doc/debug-sections.txt?rev=1.15&content-type=text/x-cvsweb-markup&only_with_tag=HEAD)

Comment: Right now, I don't want to force anything. If our proxy isn' caching it .. then i'm guessing other's aren't too. As such, I want to prove this is the case -> that if our proxy isn't caching .. why? Any links to info about those debug_options?

Comment: Good thinking 99, had to go looking, its in cvs: http://www.squid-cache.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb.cgi/squid/doc/debug-sections.txt?rev=1.15&content-type=text/x-cvsweb-markup&only_with_tag=HEAD

You might need an actual squid developer to tell you specifically which of those options will tell you about MISS processing (as they relate to source-code sections). At a guess: 11, 31, 65, with as high a level as necessary to receive the "why".. (1=low, 3=high..don't know if it goes higher)

Comment: Found this page that details it a bit better:
http://etutorials.org/Server+Administration/Squid.+The+definitive+guide/Chapter+16.+Debugging+and+Troubleshooting/16.2+Debugging+via+cache.log/